# Freeing memory that was allocated with malloc / Valgrind error

Tags: c

I'm just learning C and don't understand why this little piece of code causes a memory leak:

```
mem_ptr=(char*)malloc(24);

if (mem_ptr == NULL){
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

mem_ptr="TEST";
printf("%s\n",mem_ptr);

free(mem_ptr);
```

When I run it, Valgrind tells me:

```
==17900== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==17900==    at 0x4C2B75D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:468)
==17900==    by 0x40086F: main (main.c:69)
==17900==  Address 0x40099f is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==17900== 
==17900== 
==17900== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17900==     in use at exit: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==17900==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 24 bytes allocated
==17900== 
==17900== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17900==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==17900==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17900==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17900==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17900==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17900== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==17900== 
==17900== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17900== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: `mem_ptr = "TEST"` doesn't copy the string into your allocated memory, it simply overwrites the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a `strcpy()`:

```
mem_ptr=(char*)malloc(24);
mem_ptr="TEST";
```

This threw away the only pointer to the allocated space.  When you tried to free `"TEST"` then [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) complained that it wasn't allocated memory (and it was right).  And you'd already leaked the 24 bytes you allocated.

Corrected:

```
mem_ptr = (char*)malloc(24);

if (mem_ptr == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

strcpy(mem_ptr, "TEST");
printf("%s\n", mem_ptr);

free(mem_ptr);
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Don't really understand why, but I guess I will when I'm further through the tutorials.

Comment: Study strings and pointers.  The problem is that C string copying has to be done by `strcpy()` or one of its relatives.  Remember: `mem_ptr` is simply a pointer.  You can assign values to it via `malloc()` — as you did, perfectly correctly.  You can also assign values to it such as a literal string — which changes the pointer, the address that it points at.  Assignment does not copy the characters around; it only changes the pointer.  This is different from most other languages you might have learned (Python, Perl, Java, C#, ...).

Comment: I have removed the cast so the corrected code is really corrected.

Comment: I've reinstated the cast because I don't object to it, and even prefer it — notwithstanding other people's arguments against the practice.

Comment: Will definitely have to get more used to pointers. Thanks again!